convert column amount logic
i have serial 2d data.
For example
original data is 5x2.
i want to convert 3x4.
data amount is variable.
so must repeat by loop.
// serial data (serial)
1-1 1-2 1-3 1-4 1-5 2-1 2-2 2-3 2-4 2-5

// original data for (5x2)
1-1 1-2 1-3 1-4 1-5
2-1 2-2 2-3 2-4 2-5

// wish data to (3x4)
1-1 1-2 1-3
2-1 2-2 2-3

1-4 1-5
2-4 2-5

// wish data (serial)
1-1 1-2 1-3 2-1 2-2 2-3 1-4 1-5 2-4 2-5

i tried by following code (java).
but i cannot find one more loop.
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    static int ORIGINAL_COLUMNS = 5;
    static int MAX_COLUMNS = 3;
    
    static List<String> serialList = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("1-1");
        add("1-2");
        add("1-3");
        add("1-4");
        add("1-5");
        
        add("2-1");
        add("2-2");
        add("2-3");
        add("2-4");
        add("2-5");
    }};
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List finalList = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < serialList.size(); i += ORIGINAL_COLUMNS) {            
            for (int j = i; j < i + MAX_COLUMNS; j++) {
                finalList.add(serialList.get(j));
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(finalList);
    }
}

// result (wrong)
// second row is gone.
[1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-1, 2-2, 2-3]

you can test and check by paiza.io (i cannot attach snippets. why?)
https://paiza.io/projects/hN8d5ObIElcZIkdd8hlVmA?language=java

You can use 2 lists. One that takes the first 3 items in a row and one that takes the last 2. Then join those lists.

FYI, snippets only work for JS/HTML/CSS.

@001 This little bit easier to understand.  i will try with this way.

@001 I understand! i will use snippets when run with js/html/css

The original list
1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-52-1, 2-2, 2-3, 2-4, 2-5
can be divided into groups representing its slices limited by MAX_COLUMNS:
Group 01-1, 1-2, 1-3,1-4, 1-52-1, 2-2, 2-3,2-4, 2-5
Group 11-1, 1-2, 1-3,1-4, 1-52-1, 2-2, 2-3,2-4, 2-5
Each group contains a maximum number of rows determined by the size of a serialList and the number of ORIGINAL_COLUMNS.
An initial source item index is calculated using the current group and row indexes:group * MAX_COLUMNS + row * ORIGINAL_COLUMNS
Additional adjustments are needed to handle the limits of MAX_COLUMNS and a serialList.
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    int groups = (int) Math.ceil((double) ORIGINAL_COLUMNS / MAX_COLUMNS);
    int groupRem = ORIGINAL_COLUMNS % MAX_COLUMNS;
    int rows = (int) Math.ceil((double) serialList.size() / ORIGINAL_COLUMNS);
    
    for (int g = 0; g < groups; g++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            
            int startCol = g * MAX_COLUMNS + r * ORIGINAL_COLUMNS;
            int cols = (g == groups - 1) && groupRem > 0 ? groupRem : MAX_COLUMNS;
            int endCol = Math.min(startCol + cols, serialList.size());
            
            for (int i = startCol; i < endCol; i++) {
                finalList.add(serialList.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(finalList);
}

Output:
[1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-1, 2-2, 2-3, 1-4, 1-5, 2-4, 2-5]


Thank you for your code! i tried with this code, but unfortunately it not worked if ORIGINAL_COLUMNS more than MAX_COLUMNS twice.
    add("1-1");
    add("1-2");
    add("1-3");
    add("1-4");
    add("1-5");
    add("1-6");
    add("1-7");
    
    add("2-1");
    add("2-2");
    add("2-3");
    add("2-4");
    add("2-5");
    add("2-6");
    add("2-7");
    
    add("3-1");
    add("3-2");
    add("3-3");
    add("3-4");
    add("3-5");
    add("3-6");
    add("3-7");


current result is:
[1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-1, 2-2, 2-3, 3-1, 3-2, 3-3, 1-4, 1-5, 1-6, 1-7, 2-4, 2-5, 2-6, 2-7, 3-4, 3-5, 3-6, 3-7]
expect result is:
[
1-1, 1-2, 1-3,
2-1, 2-2, 2-3,
3-1, 3-2, 3-3,
1-4, 1-5, 1-6,
2-4, 2-5, 2-6,
3-4, 3-5, 3-6,
1-7,
2-7,
3-7
]

My mistake, it is apparently more complex task. I have just posted an update with a different solution.
